# iPhone: Customizing group table cell border style

Tags: iphone, border, uitableview

I have customized group table cell background where I am using following code to draw table cell border. The border appears correct but it always appear solid line. Is there anyway to make it etched/dotted line? What do I need to modify in following code?

```
 -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [borderColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);
    .....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `CGContextSetLineDash` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html). This allows you to set a variety of dash patterns.